# jQuery append blade templating syntax

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form that includes the two elements below along with 4 others:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="st1a">State</label>
            <select class="form-control st1a">
                @foreach (Format::states() as $state)
                    <option> {{ $state }} </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="zc1a">Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control zc1a">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Format::states()` simply returns an array of all 50 state abbreviations.  In the form, the user is providing address history.

This means they need to have the ability to click my glypicon plus symbol that appends an identical new form.

However, when this form is appended, it appends `{{ $state }}` in the select as the only option.  I understand why..

Is there anyway to work around this and have it loop and show the states in the select?

Comment: That should work. Do you mind adding the javascript function you use to add a new row?

Comment: $('.add_ah').click(function() {
    $('.address_history').append('//all html here');
});

Comment: `.add_h` being the plus icon and `.address_history` being the div that contains all of the added forms.

Comment: It's probably because blade templating is run when the page is loaded and jQuery is appending the content as HTML, right?

There's got to be some alternative though.

Comment: Thats right! I'm writing a solution in an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the browser doesn't understand blade syntax (as you mentioned in the comments), you will need to obtain the parsed html somehow. One way of doing that would be something like this.

```
var html = $('.row').parent().html();
$('.address_history').append(html);
```

However that might not work, for example if you load the page without any rows. If that is the case you need to have a template row that can be used to stamp out the new rows and always is included. Something like this.

```
<div class="template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="st1a">State</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="st1a">
                    @foreach (Format::states() as $state)
                    <option> {{ $state }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zc1a">Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zc1a">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript for a new row:

```
var html = $('.template').html();
$('.address_history').append(html);
```

Comment: This works with the states.  Thank you very much.

However... I have another input (for a date) with a class, and I use a masking JS file that masks the date and forces it to be mm/dd/yyyy.

However, when I append the new content it isn't masked.  Is there anyway to have this work too?

Comment: Sure! The masking plugin doesn't know about the recently added html. Simply reinitialising it should work though. If you have problems, tell me which plugin you are using and I can see if I can assist you.

Comment: Then you should simply be able to call the mask function again after you have added the new row, for example `$(".date").mask("99/99/9999");`.